# ESLint exhaustive deps rule for useEffect causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I've been using React for three weeks I guess, so bear with my lack of react knowledge.

I want to use `useEffect` whenever a certain state changes. But eslint exhaustive deps states that I should include more dependencies, which in turn triggers `useEffect` even though I don't want to

this works fine:

```js
useEffect(() => {
     //do something
},[stateOne])
```

this causes an infinite loop:

```js
useEffect(() => {
     //do something
},[stateOne, stateTwo])
```

While it may sound vague, the idea is that is it not ideal to just put a certain `useEffect` dependency so that it triggers only when that dependency changes? I thought the purpose of `useEffect` is that you have the option to trigger something depending on a certain dependency only.

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? if it is simply a warning then you can ignore it.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop, it means that you're changing something in your useEffect, which is also in the dependency array. 

But without more code, we cannot point where :)

Comment: @HasanAli just a warning, though it may be a bad practice to ignore it even though I know what dependency should i put to trigger the useEffect.

Comment: you need to add more details about your situation, otherwise just read this: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies

Comment: we don't know enough to help you given what you have posted, but in addition to the link above, please also read https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect